# Data migration - development to production - OrientDb

Tags: orientdb

I'm using an orientdb server for developments. Work great. Has classes, about to add support for files, etc. I'm about to provision a server on Azure for orientdb for testing by external people.

Question is

- What is the database migration plan as in how to move data between the test database and the development database? Currently, it is just data but soon files will be added. *coming from EF background*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply make a copy of db folder from test instance to develop.
Alternatively you can do an export (in.gz format) from test and then import in develop

Comment: Ok. Will the export also include any uploaded files or that will have to be copied manually as well? I'm yet to try saving binary data. Also, in the case where I want to sync structure and not data, is it possible?

Comment: I tried to export a DB with a binary data inside, I re-imported in another DB and there are no problem, the binary data was there. (I create the DB upload the file by Java).